What's a word describing movement from one side to another?
"He walked across the bridge" means he walked entire length of the bridge from one end to other end.
How do I describe the movement width-wise of bridge just like we used the word across for describing the movement length wise.

He walked to the opposite parapet.

He swerved back and forth.

Do you mean going back and forth, or crossing it width-wise just once? Both answers so far are for repeated crossings.

@Barmar I thought the question was fairly clear that he is not walking along the bridge at all. He "crosses the bridge" but from one side to the other, not from one end to the other.

@WeatherVane Me too, but the people who answered interpreted it otherwise.

Too bad this question was migrated; it has nothing to do with learner’s English. (If it did, you’d find lots of easy answers in the comments.)

@Barmar I agree. I think that "he walked across the bridge" could mean either the length  or the width. Either is equally possible without further context.

@PeterJennings Since walking width-wise is not a common way to use a bridge, I think it would always be interpreted as meaning the length. You need to be explicit if you're going the other direction, unless the context makes it obvious.

@Barmar I was coming from a logical / context point of view, not a probabilistic one. Agreed it is much more likely that he was traversing the length of the bridge, but what if he was playing Poohsticks?

Context would normally be sufficient.

Now one day Pooh and Piglet and Rabbit and Roo were all playing Poohsticks together. They had dropped their sticks in when Rabbit said "Go!" and then they had hurried across to the other side of the bridge, and now they were all leaning over the edge, waiting to see whose stick would come out first. But it was a long time coming, because the river was very lazy that day, and hardly seemed to mind if it didn't ever get there at all.  (The House at Pooh Corner, IN WHICH Pooh Invents a New Game and Eeyore Joins In.)

No doubt here what "the other side", means.

So I need to describe the context also.

Less "need to describe context"  Instead "Naturally the context would allow one to understand. It's hard to imagine a "real" situation in which "the other side" would not be understood.  In my example, Milne doesn't "describe the context".  He just writes about the game and you understand.

Simple terms to describe crossing  the width of a bridge:
OP's Query:

"He walked across the bridge".
means he walked the entire length of the bridge, from one end to the other.

"He crossed the bridge on foot".
also conveys the same meaning.
However,
"He walked across the road at the zebra crossing".
means he moved from one side of the road to the other (not from one end to the other).
If you want to describe movement across the width of the bridge (side to side) rather than its length (end to end), you could say:

"He moved laterally across/on the bridge."
"He walked from one side of the bridge to the other side."
"He crossed the width of the bridge."
"He walked sideways across the bridge."

English doesn't have a single, commonly used word equivalent to "across" for this specific side-to-side context, so phrasing often depends on clarity and context.

The phrase opposite parapet as commented is good.  ResearchGate has this diagram.
He crossed over to the opposite parapet.
